# Flask message flashing fails across redirects

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm currently working on a project using [Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28programming%29) and [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine). Calling `get_flashed_messages()` returns empty when I flash a message then use a `redirect()`:

```
@views.route('/todo/add', methods=["POST"])
def add_todo():
    flash('hey')
    return redirect(url_for('todo_list'))
```

However, if I comment out

```
# SERVER_NAME = 'localhost'
```

then it seems to work fine. My problem is that I have to use subdomains so I need SERVER_NAME to be set.

What is the deal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it!
The trick is to set server name to something with dots.

So 'localhost' became 'app.local' and app.local should be added to /etc/hosts, pointing to the same address as localhost.

From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#builtin-configuration-values):

> Please keep in mind that not only
>   Flask has the problem of not knowing
>   what subdomains are, your web browser
>   does as well. Most modern web browsers
>   will not allow cross-subdomain cookies
>   to be set on a server name without
>   dots in it. So if your server name is
>   'localhost' you will not be able to
>   set a cookie for 'localhost' and every
>   subdomain of it. Please chose a
>   different server name in that case,
>   like 'myapplication.local' and add
>   this name + the subdomains you want to
>   use into your host config or setup a
>   local bind.

Comment: I found that just commenting out SERVER_NAME got it to work. I previously had `SERVER_NAME = 127.0.0.1:5000`.

Comment: Side note, I need to change .dev to .local in my environment.

Answer (score 3):

did you set up cookies to work across all subdomains?

by default they are only readable on the domain that set them

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any idea how to do this? I see that you can call set_cookie() but I don't really know where I would do that... http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects