# How do I use ACL with webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine, acl, access-control, tipfy, webapp2

I'm a huge fan of [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/), but it's no longer being maintained. [Webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html) seems to have take its place, so I was wondering: how do I use [access control lists](http://www.tipfy.org/docs/api/tipfy.ext.acl.html) if I'm using webapp2 instead of Tipfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to port it to webapp2. It should not be hard. Here're a few tips:

- `cached_property` is available in `webapp2.cached_property` (they are equivalent)
- the call to `get_request()` should use `webapp2.get_request()`
- You can simply copy `PickleProperty` to use in your port.
- `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` is available in `os.environ` (it is the app version).

Everything else should work as it is (after taking a quick look). There are few dependencies in that module; it is mostly some datastore models.

Comment: Thanks, @moraes. On a related note, do you recommend that people now use webapp2 instead of tipfy? I think tipfy is a great little framework.

Comment: I do, and posted an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774371/flask-vs-webapp2-for-google-app-engine/6786745#6786745