# Difference between Flask and Webapp2 (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

I am still collecting information but it seems that i can't figure out what the difference of those two frameworks are.

Currently I am using webapp2 with jinja2 and wtforms. It comes right out of the box in GAE and works fine.

If i compare flask and webapp2 i can only see that flask has jinja and wtforms already integrated, so no big deal there.

If i compare the two docs it seems that both frameworks have much in common

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/

Just have some start problems with flask to get in running locally on my windows machine.

At least the docu of flask seems to be very nice. It's really nice written and very clear.

I already searched around the web and i could not find any information about the differences.

[Flask vs webapp2 for Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774371/flask-vs-webapp2-for-google-app-engine)

So , what are the differences ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flask abstracts a bit more away than webapp2 does. It's (optionally) function-based, so you don't need to make handler classes for everything. The decorator syntax used for route handling is a bit more succinct. All in all, though, they're equally powerful and anything you can do in one you can do in the other. If you already know webapp2, there's no reason I can think of to start using Flask.

Comment: One reason to use Flask is the longer term plan to move away from GAE, as in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I am all in on webapp2, hosting my apps for years on GAE.
However if you long term plans include moving 
away from GAE to Google Compute Engine or Container Engine, or to AWS EC2, you might consider Flask. Thought webapp2 [provides some support for out-of-GAE](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html), it is still more specific to GAE, at least that is my feeling.

I myself do consider moving away from GAE, so Django and Flask are on my radar to evaluate. From what I gather Flask is lightweight (as is webapp2) and both use Jinja2 templates, so I shall start with Flask.